Why is unshift so much faster than shift?
I am trying to build a fast queue and seeing my two options,
shift <- [1][2][3][4] <- push
unshift -> [4][3][2][1] -> pop

, I was pretty stunned to find that there is such huge difference between them, so I investigated and found the bottleneck being shift.
I understand why push and pop are faster than unshift and shift, because all elements in the array need to be adjusted for the latter two. But why is there such huge difference between unshift and shift? What I expected is a difference on the scale of push vs pop, since they both manipulate either the last or first elements - an operation which I assumed would take about the same time.
What am I missing that makes the shift 14x slower than unshift, whereas pop is only <2x slower than its counterpart push?
Times in milliseconds.
push 2.600000023841858
pop 4.100000023841858

unshift 989.2999999523163
shift 14029.299999952316

push/shift 14032.600000023842
unshift/pop 993.7999999523163

Tested in Chrome Version 131.0.6778.109 and Node.js v20.14.0 on Windows 10. I get different results in both, but on the same scale.


function test(repeats, array, method, arg) {
  const start = performance.now()
  for (let i=0; i < repeats; i++) array[method](arg)
  return performance.now() - start
}

let arr, start
let length = 100000

start = performance.now()
arr = []
console.log("push", test(length, arr, "push", 1))
assert(arr.length === length, "Not expected length")
  
console.log("shift", test(length, arr, "shift"))
assert(arr.length === 0, "Not expected length")

console.log("push/shift", performance.now() - start)

start = performance.now()
arr = []
console.log("unshift", test(length, arr, "unshift", 1))
assert(arr.length === length, "Not expected length")
  
console.log("pop", test(length, arr, "pop"))
assert(arr.length === 0, "Not expected length")

console.log("unshift/pop", performance.now() - start)

function assert(condition, message) { if (!condition) throw message }




I can't reproduce this. I get shift 381 unshift 376.7 in the latest Chrome on MacBook M1.

If your question is just about shift and unshift, can you remove everything related to push and pop from the MRE?

must be browser specific. Firefox: I get shift 7, unshift 4, Edge: 220/291, Chrome: 218/289 - (yes, firefox is 30 to 70 times faster) - seeing as shift/unshift are completely different functions (shift shortens the array, unshift lengthens it) the comparison between them is meaningless

@Bravo But they both require shifting the contents of the array, just in opposite directions. So it's reasonable to expect them to have similar performance.

@Barmar "both require shifting the contents" --- shift can just move pointer to the head of the array and compact periodically, achieving O(1) time performance.

@zerkms That's what I thought, but then why is unshift the fast one? It can't be done with simple pointer increment.

@Bravo I don't know what bun refers to, is that another JS engine?

So the OP needs to tell us what JS engine they're using. None of our attempts have duplicated their result of unshift being an order of magnitude faster than shift.

MacBook M1: Safari shift 6 unshift 1093. Firefox shift 6 unshift 7

node.js shift 802 unshift 765

@Bravo I'm version 20.15.0. I don't use node much, so I don't bother updating it.

This reason is related to stack management, in the case of a shift there is only one pointer to manage, while in the case of unshift there are at least 2, and a possible reorganization of the stack depending on the implementations.

I added my environment version to the post. @MisterJojo That sounds reasonable, but would logically go opposite to what I measured where shift is 10x slower than unshift. Barmar it's exactly as you say. My expectation was that they both perform similar action with pointers/content under the hood, yet there is 10x difference.

I've voted to close because this question asks about the performance of code that wasn't provided. If you want to know why an implementation is slower or faster, read and profile the code. It's not specified that shift has to be slower or faster than unshift. In addition, I get shift 3 and unshift 4 in Firefox with Debian. It looks like shift is faster there.

@jabaa I literally provided the test case that exhibits said behavior, don't be ridiculous. If the reason, however, was that this is platform specific and that there is no reason to think that shift and unshift should be comparable, I am fine with that. My thinking was just since both manipulate the first element of an array, it would make sense to have similar performance (much like push vs pop), but what do I know - hence why this QA. I could reword if that was the case, but closing, because "failed to provide code" is plain ridiculous.

You asked about the performance difference of two specific implementations but you didn't provide the implementations. How could anybody answer why your specific implementation of unshift is faster than shift if you don't provide the code? The problem is similar to Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? but you didn't even provide a link.

@jabaa what are you talking about. It's Array.prototype.unshift, Array.prototype.shift.

On my computer, shift is faster than unshift.

@jabaa Thanks, post that as the answer and I will accept it.

How does it answer the question "Why is unshift so much faster than shift?"

Means it's platform/PC specific. That's a valid answer too.

IMO, that's not the question. You specified two implementations and an OS. And that's why I voted to close.

That's a valid question from the point of view of a perplexed individual who doesn't know how the engine works. It's just as valid as this one Why is popping from a list time consuming as compared to appending?

The question is from 2013 and 11 years old. I'm here for 3 years and in this time much has changed. Please don't use an 11 years old question as a reference for your current question.

@jabaa welp ¯\(ツ)/¯ ... I appreciate that you didn't downvote my question despite having this argument. That's all I can add to this.
